# Unexpected Razor compilation error using VS2015 .net 4.51: Google namespace not found

Tags: c#, razor, google-api-dotnet-client

The error is:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

It occurs on the rendering of a template file begining with

```
@using Google.Apis.Requests
@using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;

@model Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Events
```

It appeared after I changed Google.Client.Api assemblies from 1.9.3 to 1.10 using Nuget package.
All the necessary Google assemblies are referenced in the project.

Strange thing is that VS intellisense perfectly sees the namespace and can open the Events class. And all the c# code compiles normally.

Comment: Did you try to clean your build folder completely and build again?

Comment: Thanks for so fast answer. Yes I cleaned everything. I am trying to see if there could be a pb between vs 2015 / razor and Portable Libraries format but nothing at that time.

Comment: @peleyal thanks, I think it was related to portable format, the poor info I found provided a solution without any clear understanding
[here](http://www.lyalin.com/2014/04/25/the-type-system-object-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-reference-mvc-pcl-issue/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution it was a web.config problem, I had to insert the Googles APIs as this

```
<system.web>
<compilation targetFramework="4.5.1">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="Google.Apis, Version=1.10.0.25332, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab" />
    <add assembly="Google.Apis.Core, Version=1.10.0.25331, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab" />
    <add assembly="Google.Apis.Calendar.v3, Version=1.10.0.157, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab" />
    <add assembly="Orchard.Framework"/>
    <add assembly="Orchard.Core"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: Feel free to "accept" your own answer as the solution. See  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking and other answers on Meta.